# A bit complex bootstrap responsive col-layout

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

**I have three elements inside a box :**

1) A dropdown (left)

2) A searchfield and a button (right after the dropdown)

3) A "New article" button (to the right)

On desktop, everything looks like it should (Everything is nicely aligned next to eachother)..

**but on mobile (col-sm and lower) i'm trying to accomplish the following :**

1) dropdown (left)

2) searchfield and button (left underneath the dropdown)

3) "New article" button to the right-top

Have googled around for pretty long now, and haven't been able to find a solution.

Here's my code so far, which.. doesn't work :

```
<div class="input-group">
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                <div style="float: left; margin-top: 5px">
                    <p style="color: #666">Nyheter for: &nbsp;</p>
                </div>
                <div style="float: left">
                    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" CssClass="form-control smalltext" Style="height: 30px;" ID="ddlNewsFilter" ItemType="Servicelayer.ClubClassTeam" DataValueField="Id" DataTextField="Name" AutoPostBack="True" AppendDataBoundItems="True">
                        <asp:ListItem Text="- Velg lag -" Value="0" />
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                <div style="float: left">
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtSearch" CssClass="pagemenu-item" placeholder="Søk" />
                </div>
                <div style="float: left">
                    &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnClearFilter" CssClass="btn btn-default btn-sm" OnClick="btnClearFilter_OnClick">
                <i class="dark fa fa-close"></i>
                    </asp:LinkButton>
                </div>
                <div style="float: left">
                    <asp:Button runat="server" CssClass="item" ID="lnkSearch" Text="Søk" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <div style="float: right">
            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" CssClass="item" ID="lnkNewArticle" Text="Ny artikkel" OnClick="lnkNewArticle_Click" Visible="False" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone correct this for me so i can get my so long desired result ?

Comment: It would be very helpful to understand what you are currently experiencing.  One thing I can tell for sure is that your dropdown and your search bar should technically be on the same line all the way down to the xs size becasue of the xs-6 column size.  A column is 12 blocks.  6+6=1 row.  The standard bootstrap documentation should give you some good info on how their grid works http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you try to achieve on mobile requires changing the order of elements. You have two options to achieve this;(a) Order elements with javascript, (b) Use bootstrap's push and pull classes. You can change the order, for example, col-md-**pull**-4.

Comment: Voila!.. ofcourse!... just read up on pull and push (which i haven't used before), and it gave me new insight on how to pull this off :) thanks...

Comment: yeah, push/pull is not highlighted much in the bootstrap's documentation. good luck ;)